# mvc framework for winforms .net

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller

Please suggest a good MVC framework for Winforms.

Comment: Also there is excelent article series of Jeremy Miller "Building your own CAB" explaining in details different MVP and MVC patterns with the use of WinForms, and how to test UI in details: http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx

Comment: <a href="http://www.ffentityframework.net">This</a> is a MVC-Solution in Combination with O/R-Mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mvcsharp.org/
Welcome to the MVC# home page
MVC# - is a Model-View-Presenter framework for .NET platform. It allows taking advantage of the MVP pattern with minimal effort required. As a result applications gain 3-tier structure, become better structured and easier to maintain.

MVC# Overview - an introduction to MVC# Framework.
10-Minute Example - a simple example of using MVC# Framework.

For more information examine the Documentation section of the website.

If you're feeling yourself ready, just proceed to the Download page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF (MVC application block for WPF/Silverlight)

http://blogs.msdn.com/priozersk/archive/2008/11/04/mobile-mvc-framework-part-4-passing-data-between-controllers.aspx (MVC framework for .NET Compact Framework)

Regards,
tamberg

Answer (score 0):

CAB isn't too bad

Answer (score 0):

Smart Client Software Factory:

http://www.codeplex.com/smartclient